# hover on a div to increase the width and show more content

Tags: html, css

I have the below HTML code which has left and right navigation div. When I hover the mouse I am able to expand the div's width. I am not able to display anything within the div.

I am trying to achieve something like msn.com [sample html interface I am trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmS2X.png)

I wanted to have a left and right navigation to allow my users view next and previous page. And I wanted my users to see a image when the user hovers the mouse over the link.

```css
div.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  border: thin black solid;
  transition: width 2s;
}

div.a:hover {
  width: 300px;
  border: thin black solid;
}

div.span:hover {
  display: block;
}

#hover-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div style='padding-bottom: 1000px'>
    <h1>The transition Property</h1>
    <h1>The transition Property</h1>
    <h1>The transition Property</h1>
    <h1>The transition Property</h1>

    <div style='position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 0px; top: 290px;'>
      <div style='float:left;'>
        <div class='a'>&gt;</div>
          <span id="hover-content">This is what i see</span>
        </div>

      <div style='float: right;'>
        <div class='a'>&lt;</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have set `#hover-content` to `display: none;` so it won't be visible.

You need to make it visible on hover using something like :

```
.nav:hover .hover-content {
  display: block;
}
```

See the snippet below for a complete example.
Note, that I cleaned it up and used classes instead of inline css.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: thin black solid;  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s;
}

.nav-left {
  float: left;
}

.nav-right {
  float: right;
}

.nav:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.hover-content {
  display: none;
}

.nav:hover .hover-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>The transition Property</h1>

    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='nav nav-left'>
        <div class='a'>&gt;</div>
        <span class='hover-content'>
            This is what i see
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class='nav nav-right'>
        <div class='a'>&lt;</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```